# String To NSDate (null)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The date string is as follows

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000`

However, this conversion is returning NULL

```
NSString *dateString = [_sourceData valueForKey:@"theDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFromString description]);
```

`dateString` logs : `2016-01-06 14:23:08 +0000`

Comment: _sourceData is an nsdictionary and 'theDate' is a string in that.

Comment: So it should be `objectForKey:`.  Not that that will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format should end in `Z` instead of `a` if  you want to match the string `2016-01-06 14:23:08 +0000`. `a` matches `AM` or `PM`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

You can find out more about date format patterns [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Absolutely right, thanks for the added resource as well. I'll accept when I can.